# Ways to L tromino tile a mutilated chessboard

Tags: combinatorial-geometry

Suppose we have a 2^n×2^n board. I understand the proof that you can use any rotation of L shaped trominoes and a monomino to fill the board completely, given you can mix different rotations in the same tiling.
I am stuck trying to devise a way to count the ways to tile such a board for any given n. I know the base cases, n = 0, 1 have one tiling respectively, but am stuck trying to use that to count for larger boards. I’ve tried breaking a n=2 (4 x 4) boated into n/2 sub problems but run into an issue there because filling the quadrant with the one monimo is possible, and then adding a tromino to the center such the remaining quadrants are sub problems makes me think each board has only 4 ways to tile? Someone please correct my logic/ help me find the proper recurrence please!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: The 4x4 board with the corner missing has a unique tiling, but the 8x8 board with the corner missing can be tiled in 30355 ways according to my computer program, most of which to not split into 4x4 subproblems.

Comment: $30355$ doesn’t seem to lead to a relevant OEIS entry.